# How to configure subversion auto-props for unix scripts with no .sh suffix?

Tags: svn, configuration

Not all of my bash shell script end in .sh.  Some have no suffix at all.

In my subversion auto-props configuration I have...

```
*.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable;svn:keywords="Author Date Id HeadURL Revision"
```

...and it works.  But how can I configure it to also pick up the shell scripts with no suffix.

In my case they are the only files in my workspace that do not have a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This regex should find all filenames without a `.` in them: [^.]* = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable;svn:keywords="Author Date Id HeadURL Revision"</strike>

**SOLUTION**

This [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) should match any filename that contains any number of characters, followed by any single character that is not a dot, followed by three or more characters.

```
*[!\.]??? = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable;svn:keywords="Author Date Id HeadURL Revision"
```

**TEST**

I tested this on my linux box:

```
[msherov@*** testmatch]$ uname -a
Linux ***.***.com 2.6.18-53.1.4.el5 #1 SMP Wed Nov 14 10:37:27 EST 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[msherov@*** testmatch]$ ls -alt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 msherov wheel   4096 Aug  7 08:42 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel      0 Aug  7 08:42 whatever.pp.p
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel      0 Aug  7 08:42 whatever.bat.p.p
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel      0 Aug  7 08:39 whatever.bat.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel      0 Aug  7 08:07 omething2
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel      0 Aug  7 08:06 something
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel      0 Aug  7 08:06 whatev.jpg
drwx------ 6 msherov msherov 4096 Aug  7 08:06 ..
[msherov@*** testmatch]$ ls -l ./*[!\.]???
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel 0 Aug  7 08:07 ./omething2
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel 0 Aug  7 08:06 ./something
-rw-r--r-- 1 msherov wheel 0 Aug  7 08:42 ./whatever.pp.p
```

**CAVEATS**

As you can see, this only excludes files with the classic 3 character extensions, so if you happen to be a c-sharp developer (uses `.cs`), or are using it on an html directory (uses `.html`), this won't work.

**POSSIBLE WORKAROUNDS**

If you can find a glob pattern (I couldn't!) that matches "one or more characters" (as opposed to `*` which matches zero or more) or that matches "end of line", you can replace the `???` with that and the glob would work for variable length extensions.

Comment: I'll try it Monday when I'm back at work.  Didn't realize I could use regex.

Comment: Actually, no. You're right. You have to use glob pattern matching instead of regex. Updating now.

Comment: Surely(?), you could use .* as the regex matching part, that is, a single character, followed by zero or more chars, after the proper [dot]

Comment: @PhilipOakley, no, you want things that contain no dot. It's a glob, not a regex, so `.*` would mean a literal `.` followed by anything, which is incorrect. He wants to match things that don't contain an extension, which means, "anything followed by NOT a dot, followed by any three characters". This will exclude files that have a standard 3 character extension, which is the best a glob can do in this case.

Comment: @Mike: noted, sorry for the confusion.